# Adding a third party dependecy in Pod cause to disable code coverage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have multiple modules in my app and managed by POD file. I was able to get code coverage for each module but when I added a third party framework inside a module (in POD file), I can execute test cases but code coverage is zero for module.

Here is my POD file

BEFORE:

```
def place_kit
  # currently no module specific dependencies
end

target 'PlaceKit' do
  project 'Frameworks/PlaceKit/PlaceKit.xcodeproj'
  place_kit

  target 'PlaceKitTests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end
end
```

AFTER:

```
def place_kit
  # currently no module specific dependencies
end

target 'PlaceKit' do
  project 'Frameworks/PlaceKit/PlaceKit.xcodeproj'
  kit_payments /// Added Third party framwork and now code coverage is zero for PlaceKit
  place_kit

  target 'PlaceKitTests' do
    inherit! :complete
  end
end
```

Now when added *kit_payments* in module, cant see code covrage for module. I did check *code_coverage* in app.

I cant make any change inside *kit_payments*, please guide how to enable code coverage after adding third party framework *kit_payments*